# stutter every 500 ms using nvidia-driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, gigabyte

I wanted to use ubuntu with the nvidia driver on my new computer but as soon as I start to use the proprietary nvidia driver everything on the screen freeze very briefly every 500 ms. I noticed when I switch to tty that the command line is flickering.

**My config :**

- CPU : Ryzen 7 2700x
- GPU : GTX 1070
- RAM : 16 Gb (Overclocked to 3200 MHz)
- STORAGE :

  - / on a M.2
  - /home on a Old Hard drive

output of " lspci -k | grep -EA3 '3D|Display|VGA' " :

```
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

**I tried (with 0 effect) :**

- switching distro  : pop os (with preinstalled nvidia driver), manjaro, debian, linux mint
- installing driver using different method : (with the .run, using graphical-driver ppa, driver manager)
- installing different driver ( 340 - 390 - 435 - 440 )
- disabling/enabling :

  - Sync to VBlank
  - Allow Flipping
  - Force Full Composition Pipeline
  - nvidia "Timer" : Thermal monitor, powerMinimizer monitor, Memory Used
- Changing monitor frequency both in nvidia-setting and ubundu display settings

I tried Windows 10 with the latest nvidia driver and it works well.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I am sure "pop os (with preinstalled nvidia driver), manjaro, debian, linux mint" are good distros, and all have their own support channels. They are off topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try another cable or another display if you see repeated messages in your /var/log/Xorg.0.log (see below).

If that doesn't help, also check this different but related issue I found in my own searches: [Ubuntu 18.04 video stutters every second regularly with nvidia GPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105528/ubuntu-18-04-video-stutters-every-second-regularly-with-nvidia-gpu/1235293)

I was having the same problem with Kubuntu on an RTX2080 on a Skylake i7 and it seemed to be due to a flaky HDMI connection to one of my displays.  The /var/log/Xorg.0.log file showed lots of connection messages for that display.  I fixed it by unplugging and reconnecting the HDMI cable to that display.

I'm not really sure what the root cause is since this is something new.  Random uninformed guess: maybe the drivers are more picky about HDMI presence detection or EDID I2C signal quality or something.

Example Xorg.0.log messages:

```
[   220.145] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): [Display brand name] (DFP-2): connected
[   220.145] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): [Display brand name] (DFP-2): Internal TMDS
[   220.145] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): [Display brand name] (DFP-2): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   220.145] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   220.718] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): [Display brand name] (DFP-2): connected
[   220.718] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): [Display brand name] (DFP-2): Internal TMDS
[   220.718] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): [Display brand name] (DFP-2): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   220.718] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   220.776] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): [Display brand name] (DFP-2): connected
[   220.776] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): [Display brand name] (DFP-2): Internal TMDS
[   220.776] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): [Display brand name] (DFP-2): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   220.776] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   221.381] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): [Display brand name] (DFP-2): connected
[   221.381] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): [Display brand name] (DFP-2): Internal TMDS
[   221.381] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): [Display brand name] (DFP-2): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   221.381] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
```

Comment: That fixed the problem the issue was caused because the cable was not fully plugged, but it is strange that windows didn't care about it .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - turns out it's caused by the "System-monitor" gnome shell extension:
https://dragoshmocrii.com/ubuntu-20-04-stuttering-animations-video/

Disabling it fixed it straight away.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers showed me that my display port cable (for the 2nd screen) was producing the same errors (connection/disconnection).

However given that i have KDE and not Gnome i was checking on other sensor-related services.

For me i could reproduce the problem by starting the sensor GUI tool **Psensor**.

once i stopped it i had no "microfreezes" anymore.

During further analysis i could limit the effect on the NVCtrl sensor provider.