# Screen freezes for roughly one frame each second

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics

After not using Ubuntu for a while I came back and noticed the following: The screen seems to "microfreeze" for a tiny amount of time roughly once per second. I noticed when moving the mouse it seems to stop a tiny bit, but the whole screen also stops when e.g. watching a video or other things, so it's not a problem with the mouse. It feels like one frame is repeated every second.

Possibly useful information:

- CPU: Ryzen 7 2700, GPU: GTX 1660 Ti
- I didn't ever had this problem in the years using Ubuntu on my machine
- I was using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver, but have now tried Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, but it doesn't fix it.
- I might have done the automatic updates
- I might have installed some libraries recently: PyTorch, Tensorflow, CUDA, CUDNN
- The only hardware change to my PC is I added a fan for better thermals
- I don't have the problem in nouveau, but I prefer the official nvidia-drivers by a lot: The second screen works better, easier settings of resolution etc,...

Things I've tried (and didn't work):

- Changing the refresh rate of both of my monitors to 60 FPS (one was 59.95 before)
- uninstalling all nvidia libraries/packages and changing to another nvidia driver
- Disabling C-states in the bios
- switching to earlier kernels
- `sudo swapoff -a` doesn't do anything about it

I would be very grateful for any suggestions how I could go about fixing this.

---

Edit: I reinstalled Ubuntu completly, but the problem persists. So probably a hardware issue? (But Windows works completly fine) I will remove the fan I installed just in case it is a weird power issue. Then I will run memcheck just to make sure. But after that I'm out of ideas, maybe someone else has any?

Edit 2: It's not the fan, it's not the memory. Could it be the BIOS/UEFI? I'm gonna play around with settings and if I can't fix it, I'm gonna install a different distro.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this post: [stutter every 500 ms using nvidia-driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230768/stutter-every-500-ms-using-nvidia-driver)

The HDMI cable of one monitor was slightly loose. Weird though that the problem didn't occur in Windows.